# Desktop not fluid, mouse and screen jump every seconds

Tags: 11.10

I'm new on ubuntu and I'm having problems of fluidity. I've installed the latest version, 11.10 in 64 bits mode and my issue is that when booting normally, mouse and screen in general jump every five seconds or so, a bit nasty. But if i launch ubuntu from recovery mode, it goes perfect and smooth.

Is there anyway of solving this or is just accept and choose recovery mode at every launch?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide some details of your hardware.  What type of graphics hardware do you have?  Are you using the standard or proprietary drivers?

Answer (score 0):

I "Believe" that there isn't a fix for 11.10, but i am told it has been fixed in 12.04.
Someone correct me if i'm wrong, but I am running 12.04 and its seems to be completely fixed.

So maybe just wait for next release.

Comment: I think that It maybe is only a problem in 64 bit version, because I have just installed the 32 in a laptop that its 32bits and after some test of rebooting, it works smooth.

Comment: @Javier So, you initially were trying to run 64-bit Ubuntu on a 32-bit laptop?